# Lotus Notes Generated Java Web Service Consumer Keeps Caching Results

Tags: java, web-services, lotus-notes

I create a java web service consumer.

Web Service Consumers -> New Web Service Consumer... -> Type: Java

Then, created a Java Agent Calling This web service.

Agents -> New Agent... -> Type: Java

Then imported the Java Web Service Consumer.

Import -> Web Service Consumer

In the java agent I call the web service method like so.

```
LotusNotesHandlerLocator locator = new LotusNotesHandlerLocator();
LotusNotesHandlerSoap handlerSoap = locator.getLotusNotesHandlerSoap();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(doc.getItemValueString("TimeInMilliseconds").trim()));
Sample sample = handlerSoap.getResult(cal);
// code for updating timestamp added here
```

Here's a sample result of the number of data retrieved from the web service.

```
Finished processing 3 document(s).
```

The web service method only returns the said documents based from the time stamp. I expect that from the next web service call it will only return 1 document. But it also includes the documents previously retrieved by the java agent.

Here's a sample result of the number of data retrieved from the web service.

```
// should only be 1
Finished processing 4 document(s).
```

It works as expected in soapUI. I tried using Apache Axis2 and JAX-WS, and they work as expected.

Any reason why notes does caching of results?
Is there a way to disable caching if it exists?

Regards,

Philip

**Lotus Notes 8.5.2 | Windows XP | JVM 1.6.0**

Comment: Check what SOAP requests and responses are actually being sent and received. That should help you find out what is going on. Also, how is the agent being triggered?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did check the SOAP request and response through soapUI and they are correct. The agent is schedule to run every 5 minutes.

Comment: I could use Axis2 to solve this problem but I get an AccessDenied exception. Our admin does not want to allow permissions for java applications to access the server.

Comment: I'm not familiar with soapUI, but a quick look suggested that it would enable you to test the provider. Does it give you a way to see what requests Domino is actually making? Is domino making the requests you expect? Is it making more requests than you expect? Is it not making some?

Comment: I did some test and here are the what I found.
There are two web services methods, in the provider.
getResult(DateTime) and getResultForTest().
When I call getResult() it always returns what getResultForTest() returns, I checked soapUI and it works perfectly.

I also check the web service consumer provided by notes and there is no problem.

Example:
   1st Run: Expecting 1 doc
         getResult() - returns 1 doc
         soapUI getResult() - returns 1 doc
   2nd Run: Expecting 2 docs
         getResult() - returns 2 docs
         soapUI getResult() - returns 3 docs (1 old one and 2 new ones)

Comment: I found the problem, when I am passing the Calendar object, the timeZone is wrong, I just need a way to convert the date/time to the timeZone of the server. Thanks kerr, I'll research the internet on how to do it. :)